# pipenv install django failed on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to install django in my vscode, but the output is like this
(my ubuntu version is 20.04),is there something wrong with my ubuntu or my python?

```
    pipenv install djangoTraceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 6, in <module>from pkg_resources import load_entry_pointFile "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 3254, in <module>def _initialize_master_working_set():File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 3237, in _call_asidef(*args, **kwargs)File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 3266, in _initialize_master_working_setworking_set = WorkingSet._build_master()File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 584, in _build_masterws.require(_requires_)File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 901, in requireneeded = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_init_.py", line 787, in resolveraise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pathlib' distribution was not found and is required by pipenv

I tried use this

`sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

but i got this

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
        command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
        module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
        from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
        from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 12, in <module>
        from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
    ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @Raida
I guess no, i got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` when i do sudo apt update, and `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'importlib-resources<2,>=1.0' distribution was not found and is required by virtualenv` when i do virtualenv --version, I've changed python version 3.8 to 3.10 before,

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt` in order to reinstall `apt_pkg` then retry `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @Raida
thanks a lot! I'll save and try it when i get the error again later but now my problem is solved by `pip install --force --upgrade pipenv`, and i also removed my python 2.7 too